# Using KAA CLIENT SDK C code for KAA 8 on a KAA 10 Server

Tags: kaa

Is it possible to migrate KAA 8 client using a KAA 10 Server? We are considering upgrading our Server to KAA 10 and are concerned that our current endpoints will no longer communicate due to the upgrade. We currently are using KAA 8 and Use the Client SDK in C.  Your thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaa 0.8 and Kaa 0.10 are not protocol-compatible. That means you should update all your clients for them to continue to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex.  We have an issue with KAA 8 and tried updating to KAA 8.1 and seemed to have issues with the client as well.  Is this the same situation as KAA 8  to KAA 10?  Also, is there a way to easily disable the Authentication to allow all devices to register so we can update the clients to the new Client? We have an issue with Authentication that is causing devices to not have a proper handshake (the key's are not regenerating in the sdk)

Comment: Due to a bug, Kaa 0.8.0 and Kaa 0.8.1 are not compatible.

Comment: Ok, any suggestions as to how to remove the authentication on the server to allow all the devices to register so we can upgrade them to KAA 10?

Comment: Log in as a tenant admin and select Trustful credentials service: https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Devices-provisioning-and-registration/#endpoint-authorization

Comment: This is very good, however, it seems to only be available in KAA 10.  Is there a way to implement this in KAA 8 so we can fix our issue and migrate to kaa 10?

Comment: Is it possible to send commands to an endpoint to remove a file? and restart the client?

Comment: You can send a notification to a client and implement the rest of the logic yourself.

Comment: Hi Alex, i dont understand your response to my question.  The question is , can you send a notification to remove a file?

Comment: You can send any notification, but attaching any business logic is your client responsibility. (e.g., you can send a notification to conquer the world, though you must implement `conquer_the_world` function first.)